# Restful web service call from link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest

On load of page, I am making a restful call and getting data. This is working fine. On click of these data (which are left navigation links) I need to make another rest call and get data. I am trying to do that from link function. Since I am new to angular js, I am not sure how good/bad it is to call from there. I tried with several examples on how to call restful web service from link function but failed to implement successfully.

My js file code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('ngdemo', []);

app.directive('collection', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member' article-data='articleData' article-content='articleContent'></member></ul>"
    }
});

app.directive('member', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<div><li><a href='#' ng-click="getContent(member.itemId)">{{member.title}}</a></li></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getContent = function(itemId) {
                //scope.articleContent.content = articleData[0].getArticleResponse.articleDetail.articleContent;
                //scope.articleContent.title = articleData[0].getArticleResponse.articleDetail.title;


                    var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getArticle",
                    params: {
                        action: "post"
                    },
                    articleContents: {
                        getArticleCriteria:{
                            articleId: itemId,
                            locale: "en_US"

                        }
                    }
                });

                return( request.then(handleSuccess,handleError));


            }

            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.tocItem)) {
                if (scope.member.hasChildren == "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.member.tocItem.length; i++) {
                        if (scope.member.tocItem.title) {
                            scope.member.tocItem.title.hide = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.append("<collection collection='member.tocItem'></collection>");    
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('apdController', function($scope, getTocService) {
    var sampdata = getTocService.getToc('bookid-1');
   $scope.tasks =sampdata;

    $scope.articleContent = {};
});


app.service(
        "getTocService",
        function( $http, $q ) {
            return({
                getToc: getToc
            });

            function getToc(bookIdvar) {
                var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getTOC",
                    params: {
                        action: "post"
                    },
                    data: {
                        getTOCCriteria:{
                        bookId: bookIdvar
                        }
                    }
                });
                return( request.then(handleSuccess,handleError));
            }        
        }

);



function handleSuccess(response){
    return (response.data);
}

function handleError( response ) {

    if (
        ! angular.isObject(response.data) ||
        ! response.data.message
        ) {
        return($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
    }
    return($q.reject(response.data.message));
}
```

on click of left nav links, I am not getting any error in browser console but its not hitting service . getContent() is the method I am trying to call on click of left nav links. Can someone please help me on this?

Edited:

Now, I am able to hit the rest service but getting "server responded with a status of 400 (Bad request)" . Request sent is

```
{
"getArticleCriteria" :{
            "articleId": "PH1234",
            "locale": "en_US" 
           }
           }
```

This is the expected request and I am able to get response in Soap UI for the same request. Any changes I need to make while calling the rest service?

Comment: the difference between `controller` and `link` functions in directive is that `controller` is precompile and `link` is postcompile, but to use `$http` you need to inject it in the directive definition - same place where you injected `$compile`

Comment: @maurycy I didn't actually get what you are telling. Can you please elaborate a little? I got some code on net and edited to bring it to current shape.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code and added the injection of $http  http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/rxjqBQ?editors=001

Comment: Thanks a lot maurycy :) It is working fine. Can you please add this an answer so that I can accept the answer

Comment: Although as a good standard for future you should put templates in single quotes `'` then use double quotes inside the template ;) it's generally good practice to put all strings in `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cleaned up code with injection of $http service into directive

```
var app = angular.module('ngdemo', []);

app.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: '<ul><member ng-repeat="member in collection" member="member" article-data="articleData" article-content="articleContent"></member></ul>'
    }
});

app.directive('member', function ($compile, $http) { //NOTE THE INJECTED $http
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: '<div><li><a href="#" ng-click="getContent(member.itemId)">{{member.title}}</a></li></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getContent = function (itemId) {
                //scope.articleContent.content = articleData[0].getArticleResponse.articleDetail.articleContent;
                //scope.articleContent.title = articleData[0].getArticleResponse.articleDetail.title;

                var request = $http({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getArticle',
                    params: {
                        action: 'post'
                    },
                    articleContents: {
                        getArticleCriteria: {
                            articleId: itemId,
                            locale: 'en_US'

                        }
                    }
                });

                return ( request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));

            };

            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.tocItem)) {
                if (scope.member.hasChildren == 'true') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.member.tocItem.length; i++) {
                        if (scope.member.tocItem.title) {
                            scope.member.tocItem.title.hide = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.append('<collection collection="member.tocItem"></collection>');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('apdController', function ($scope, getTocService) {
    $scope.tasks = getTocService.getToc('bookid-1');

    $scope.articleContent = {};
});

app.service('getTocService',
    function ($http, $q) {
        return ({
            getToc: getToc
        });

        function getToc(bookIdvar) {
            var request = $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://10.132.241.41:8082/apdpoc/services/ApdBookService/getTOC',
                params: {
                    action: 'post'
                },
                data: {
                    getTOCCriteria: {
                        bookId: bookIdvar
                    }
                }
            });
            return ( request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
        }
    }
);

function handleSuccess(response) {
    return (response.data);
}

function handleError(response) {

    if (!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
        return ($q.reject('An unknown error occurred.'));
    }
    return ($q.reject(response.data.message));
}
```